# How can I create custom fields in react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I am trying to add a bool property to a form that is toggled on/off depending on the click of button1 or button2.

When I do [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ojx3wyyjp6) on my local setup, I get the react setState error but only on the first click.

`Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.`

I imagine it is because invoking input.onChange is not expected. What is the best way to accomplish the custom input?

Comment: I am able to see that it works fine on my local. Please recheck your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find anything wrong with the downloaded setup from [above sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ojx3wyyjp6) on my local.

Probably, you have updated the code after finding a fix. Please let people know the solution if your issue is resolved or close it

Comment: Looks fine to me also.